# Sending variable from view to template django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

```
def total_rent(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    venues = Venue.objects.all()
    decorations = Decoration.objects.all()
    context1 = ({'venues': venues, 'decorations': decorations})
    if request.method == 'GET':
        rent1 = request.GET.get('venue')
        rate1 = request.GET.get('decor')
        if rent1 and rate1:
            total = int(rent1)+int(rate1)
            return render_to_response("test.html", context1, {'total':total})
        else:
            return render_to_response("test.html", context1)

    return render_to_response("test.html", context1, context)
```

tryied this for passing total back to template.html but getting error "pop expected at least 1 arguments, got 0"

template.html

```
<form action="" method="get">
{% for venue in venues %}
<input type="radio" name= "venue" id="venue{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{venue.rent }}"/>
<label for="venue{{ forloop.counter }}">{{  venue.venue_Name}}</label><br />
<img src="{{  venue.picture.url }}" alt="" width="200">
{% endfor %}
{% for decoration in decorations %}
<input type="radio" name="decor"id="decor{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ decoration.rate }}" />
<label for="decor{{ forloop.counter }}">{{  decoration.rating }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="service" />
{% if total %}
    <p>Total cost for venue and decoration: {{ total }}</p>
{% endif %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the context and context1 consistent. Try this:

```
def total_rent(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    venues = Venue.objects.all()
    decorations = Decoration.objects.all()
    context1 = ({'venues': venues, 'decorations': decorations})

    if request.method == 'GET':
        rent1 = request.GET.get('venue')
        rate1 = request.GET.get('decor')
        if rent1 and rate1:
            total = int(rent1)+int(rate1)
            context1.update({'total': total})
            return render_to_response("test.html", context1, context)
        else:
            return render_to_response("test.html", context1, context)

    return render_to_response("test.html", context1, context)
```

Or just:

```
def total_rent(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    venues = Venue.objects.all()
    decorations = Decoration.objects.all()
    context1 = ({'venues': venues, 'decorations': decorations})

    rent1 = request.GET.get('venue')
    rate1 = request.GET.get('decor')
    if rent1 and rate1:
        total = int(rent1)+int(rate1)
        context1.update({'total': total})

    return render_to_response("test.html", context1, context)
```

Note that `request.method` is `GET` by default.